# List of strings in ints ['123 121','42 23','23 23']

Tags: python, list

`['136 145', '136 149', '137 145', '138 145', '139 145', '142 149', '142 153', '145 153']`
With my list above I want to turn the elements into ints, I know that just using `[int(x) for x in mylist]` will not work. So my question is how do you turn the list I have into a list of ints.

Comment: every element in the list represends 2 ints...

Comment: What output do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the text first, *then* convert to int:

```
[map(int, elem.split()) for elem in originallist]
```

For Python 3, where `map()` returns an generator, not a list, you can nest the list comprehension:

```
[[int(n) for n in elem.split()] for elem in originallist]
```

which would work equally well under Python 2.

Quick demo:

```
>>> originallist = ['136 145', '136 149', '137 145', '138 145', '139 145', '142 149', '142 153', '145 153']
>>> [[int(n) for n in elem.split()] for elem in originallist]
[[136, 145], [136, 149], [137, 145], [138, 145], [139, 145], [142, 149], [142, 153], [145, 153]]
```

You can remove the nesting by moving the `elem.split()` loop to the outer list comprehension, to the end:

```
[int(n) for elem in originallist for n in elem.split()]
```

which gives:

```
[136, 145, 136, 149, 137, 145, 138, 145, 139, 145, 142, 149, 142, 153, 145, 153]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L = ['136 145', '136 149', '137 145', '138 145', '139 145', '142 149', '142 153', '145 153']
>>> [int(y) for x in L for y in x.split()]
[136, 145, 136, 149, 137, 145, 138, 145, 139, 145, 142, 149, 142, 153, 145, 153]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I tend to go to great lengths to avoid nested list comprehensions (I can never remember the order), I would do something like:

```
from itertools import chain
x = ['136 145', '136 149', '137 145', '138 145', '139 145', '142 149', '142 153', '145 153']
gen = chain.from_iterable(elem.split() for elem in x)
integers = [int(elem) for elem in gen]
```

Comment: I think I only like `chain.from_iterable` when it surrounds the whole expression

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> l=['136 145', '136 149', '137 145', '138 145', '139 145', '142 149', '142 153', '145 153']    
>>> map(int, re.findall(r'\d+',' '.join(l)))
[136, 145, 136, 149, 137, 145, 138, 145, 139, 145, 142, 149, 142, 153, 145, 153]
```

Comment: You don't need regex for this approach

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = ['136 145', '136 149', '137 145', '138 145', '139 145', '142 149', '142 153', '145 153']
>>> map(int, ' '.join(L).split())
[136, 145, 136, 149, 137, 145, 138, 145, 139, 145, 142, 149, 142, 153, 145, 153]
```